# how can I install linkwithin on tumblr?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi everyone I am trying to put linkwithin on my tumblr blog but when I copy and paste the code before body it doesn't work the related thumbnails posts don't appear under my blog posts:

```
<script> 
var linkwithin_site_id = 2252967; 
</script> 
<script src="linkwithin.com/widget.js"></script>; 
<a href="linkwithin.com/">
  <img src="linkwithin.com/pixel.png"; alt="Related Posts Plugin for WordPress, Blogger..." style="border: 0" />
</a>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: @Spork This is the code : <script>
var linkwithin_site_id = 2252967;
</script>
<script src="http://www.linkwithin.com/widget.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.linkwithin.com/"><img src="http://www.linkwithin.com/pixel.png" alt="Related Posts Plugin for WordPress, Blogger..." style="border: 0" /></a>

Comment: Have you tried the FAQ: http://www.linkwithin.com/faq I would also add a link to a live example of the issue.

Comment: @mikedidthis I tried but they didn't reply yet I'm still waiting :(

Comment: Again, I would add a link to the an example of the issue, so users can take a look. AS the question stands, there is very little to go off.